# How to get Python 3.4 on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Does anyone have a step by step process for a beginner to get the latest version of Python (3.4) to work on Sublime Text 3?  I tried adding Python 3 as another build but I don't think i added it correctly (the instructions were for how to add it for Sublime Text 2) because I cannot build my function when I set it to Python 3 on Sublime Text 3.  Only the basic  Python build version is working.  How can I get Python 3.4 to work?  Thanks really need help immediately

Comment: anyone? this is vital need to get 3.4 working soon.  Prefer to use sublime text

Comment: Doesn't anyone else hadv had this issue/know how to solve it??????

Answer (score 1):

Goto Tools > Build > New Build System and enter the following.

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/" }
```

Save the file and restart Sublime Text. If it still doesn't work, check if the 'path' is correct in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Build System > New Build System..
Replace this code

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "make"
}
```

with this

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

/usr/local/bin/python3 ==> python.exe path in your system
then save with a name.sublime-build. It will appear in build system. select the build system and run the python code by pressing `Ctrl + B`

Answer (score -1):

Select the menu *Tools > Build > New Build System* and enter the following:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "$file"]
    , "selector": "source.python"
    , "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}
```

After that, save it to the following (Mac-specific) directory: *~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User*

That's all there to it.

Comment: This will continue to use Python3.3 rather than the 3.4 desired by the OP. See here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257984/python3-4-on-sublime-text-3] for the full answer.