# I'm having trouble importing a Python API from GitHub

Tags: python, python-3.x, github

I'm trying to use this Python API in my project:
https://github.com/Rami114/Stockfighter

I keep getting an ImportError: No module named Stockfighter.Api

My text editor is SublimeText 3, and my code looks like this:

```
from Stockfighter.Api import StockFighterApi
```

I also tried import it using sys:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/myname/Desktop/PythonGames/Stockfighter-master/Stockfighter')

from Stockfighter.Api import StockFighterApi
```

I download the api from github in terminal using this code:

```
$ python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/Rami114/Stockfighter.git
```

This is the resulting out from that installation

> Collecting git+https://github.com/Rami114/Stockfighter.git
>     Cloning https://github.com/Rami114/Stockfighter.git to /var/folders/cg/2k70brh54y51hm65qh4dhwch0000gn/T/pip-w9ptx96u-build
>     Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Stockfighter==0.1 from git+https://github.com/Rami114/Stockfighter.git in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Stockfighter-0.1-py3.5.egg
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests-2.9.1-py3.5.egg (from Stockfighter==0.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ws4py in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ws4py-0.3.4-py3.5.egg (from Stockfighter==0.1)

I'm really new to both python and github, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you import `Stockfighter` in the REPL?

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm doing this right, as i've never used a REPL before, but I used this site https://repl.it/ and tried the same import statements as above. I received the same error each time

Comment: Type `python` at a command line and then try to import it.

Comment: The same error occurred. Should I get SublimeREPL in order to attempt this in the SublimeText Editor?

Comment: No. Doing it in the normal REPL is enough. And it shows that the module is not installed for that version of Python.

Comment: And the normal REPL is the one I used, correct?

Comment: The one from running `python` at the command line, yes.

Comment: ok, cool, thanks! Do you have any advice on how I might install the api since the "-m pip install" command doesn't appear to be working?

Comment: Looking above, you seem to have installed it under 3.x. Have you told your script to use 3.x as well?

Comment: ohhhh, that's a good call. I'll figure out how to make sure it's running on Python3.x and report back.

Comment: Attempted this code, but it did not work - $alias python=python3

Comment: An alias won't work; you need to modify the shebang line.

Comment: I got it working! Awesome! Thank you so much for walking me through everything, I really appreciate your time and patience :)

Comment: I followed this answer in order to get this working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257984/python3-4-on-sublime-text-3