# Python version and sublime build

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

All I have is a 6 year old laptop, and I am trying to learn python, so maybe I can make some money in online marketing, which will lead to me having a proper unit where I can install an IDE, unlike now, where it keeps freezing since it cant hold itself together. 
I decided to work with sublime text because it is far more lighter and also has a built-in "build" function.

here is the code I am having difficulty running(trying to download a picture):

```
import random
import urllib.request

def download(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)



download("https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png")
```

and here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kd/Desktop/pytest/python.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

i thought maybe sublime text is using the wrong version of python... here it was explained how to make sublime text use a different version of python:[Python3.4 on Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257984/python3-4-on-sublime-text-3)  but its not working. should I just kill myself?

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is 6 years old, you are probably using python 2.7, which does not have module `urllib.request`. Either upgrade your python, or use module `urllib2` (function `urlopen()`).