# Hw to run Python code on Sublime Text 3?, Just curious

Tags: python-3.x

How do I run code on sublime text?
I have many text editors but I am just curious on how you run code on sublime text.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As you've written: Sublime is a text editor - so what else do you expect from that program?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306331/how-to-run-python-code-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run python code in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306331/how-to-run-python-code-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: Yes it does answer my question.