Sublime Text 3 doesn't react to inputs
To avoid any errors or unexpected results, I will explain my problem using this simple code:
number = int(input())
print(number)

Then I ran it. I typed a value, pressed Enter and... nothing happened.
What should I do to fix this?

Please indicate how you can this code, there's not enough information here to help you.

Did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67649832/18667225 ?

@Markus, I know how to run the code. My probelam is when I run my code with input, I type that input and nothing happens.

Do you use Terminus Plug-in as suggested in that post?
