# Async def invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Using Python 3.6)

Hello !

I'm actually making a Python Discord bot (for a school project) and i'm facing a little problem at this part of the code:

```
    async def on_message(self, message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
        await self.invoke(ctx)
```

Here is the error message:

```
File "/Users/dorian/Desktop/ISN/ISNbotv2/bot.py", line 47
async def on_message(self, message):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/dorian/Desktop/ISN/ISNbotv2/bot.py"]
[dir: /Users/dorian/Desktop/ISN/ISNbotv2]
[path:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Weirdly when I launch the script with my PC the bot is working, unfortunatly I only have this error only on the MAC I HAVE to use for my school project.

Thanks for your help (and sorry if I made english mistakes, not my main langage)

Comment: Can you do `import sys; print(sys.version)` just to confirm?

Comment: @Tobias I got: 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
[Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: Well there you go -- you're on Python 2.7.10, not 3.6.

Comment: oh you're right but I also have the IDLE Python 3.6.5 on my computer but apparently Sublime Texte is using Python 2.7.10, is there a way to use 3.6 with ST3 ?

Comment: @MisubataNightcore yes, which is answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257984/python-3-4-on-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 1):

To double check your version via script. 
import sys; 
print(sys.version)

People usually install python 3.7 on top of existing python 2.x that is with the system. When running a command sometimes you will forget to run it as python3.7 instead of just simply python  which would run python2.

Therefore it causes the error "Async def invalid syntax"

Run python3.7