# Sublime Text 3 using different python version?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

This *might* be an issue with sublime text, in which case I need to open an issue. However, I thought I'd ask here first.

First of all, I have already tried all the answers mentioned here:
[Python 3.4 on Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257984/python-3-4-on-sublime-text-3)

I am running on the latest stable version od Pop!_OS, with Sublime Text installed with flatpak via the pop shop.

When I try to run this file with the answer given above, I get this:

CODE:

```py
import sys
print("Sublime is using: ", sys.version)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sublime is using:  3.7.4 (default, Nov 10 2011, 15:00:00) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
```

This doesn't seem all that bad, but I don't *have* python3.7 installed at all (at least not in the usual `/usr/bin` location). When I run `/usr/bin/env python3`, or just `python3`, I get a prompt using `python3.8`. To remove any other possible errors, I changed the sublime build to be

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "/usr/bin/env python3.8 ${file}",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
}
```

But this returns

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3.8’: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: /usr/bin/env python3.8 /home/USERNAME/Documents/MinecraftCloneButCooler/main.py]
[dir: /home/USERNAME/Documents/MinecraftCloneButCooler]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

All of this I really wouldn't mind, except that I really need some pip libraries installed, and like I said earlier, I can't seem to find any installation of python3.7 installed anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

--EDITS:--

I tried using `"shell_cmd": "python3 -u \"$file\""`, but that actually caused a new error. When I use that `shell_cmd` Sublime actually says that it can't find a build system (yes I have verified that I am using the right one in `tools > build system`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.4 on Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257984/python-3-4-on-sublime-text-3)

Comment: No, sorry but that didn't work.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Did you get an error message? The built in build system for Python executes `python`; seems like on your system that's Python 3.7 (Sublime does not come with a user version of Python pre-installed). You can see where that version is coming from by saying `which python` in a terminal.  What is the result of `which python3` as well; anything?

Comment: `which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3`. I can't give the error message right now, but I will be sure to edit that into my answer tomorrow.

Comment: In the interim, I would try using a `shell_cmd` like `"shell_cmd": "python3 -u \"$file\""` and see if that finds and runs the version that you want.